# Start MvxActivity from normal Activity?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, start-activity

Particularly the Navigation between the Views over the ViewModels looks like that:

```
ShowViewModel<InfoViewModel>();
```

Or between normal Activities:

```
context.StartActivity(typeof(InfoActivity));
```

The problem I face now (*actually I solved it in one of my latest projects by using Tinymessenger - its an event aggregator/messenger for loosely coupled communication*) but I would like to know if theres an other way!

I'm creating an optionsmenu:

```
public abstract class BaseActivityWithoutTabs<T> : MvxActivity where T : class, IMvxViewModel
{
        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            return ActivitiesHelper.CreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            return ActivitiesHelper.CreateOnOptionsItemSelectedEvent(item, this);
        }
}
```

`InfoActivity` derives from this `BaseActivityWithoutTabs`.

In the ActivitiesHelper Class (from above code) I'm creating the menu and the events:

```
public class ActivitiesHelper
{
    private const int einstellungenItemId = 0;
    private const int infoItemId = 1;

    public static bool CreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        // GroupId, ItemId, OrderId
        menu.Add(0, einstellungenItemId, 0, "Einstellungen").SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcMenuManage);
        menu.Add(0, infoItemId, 1, "Info").SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcMenuInfoDetails);
        return true;
    }

    public static bool CreateOnOptionsItemSelectedEvent(IMenuItem item, Context context)
    {
        var id = item.ItemId + 1; // (Id is zero-based :)
        if (id == 1) // First Item
        {
            context.StartActivity(typeof(SettingsShowActivity));
        }
        else if (id == 2) // Second Item
        {
            context.StartActivity(typeof(InfoActivity)); //doesn't work...
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you see I do here "`StartActivity`".. it works for the first "`SettingsShowActivity`" but thats an **PreferenceActivity**, so there no reason why it should fail. The problem is, that I would like to Start here the `InfoActivity`(as you see in code - Second Item) and this doesn't work. It opens the Activity but the List doesn't gets filled.

But if I go to a ViewModel in my project and call: `ShowViewModel<InfoViewModel>();`it works fine but this is on that place (in the ActivitiesHelper Class) not available/possible!

```
public class InfoViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public InfoViewModel()
    {
        Info info = new Info();
        info.Key = "ITS A KEYY";
        info.Value = "here we got a value";
        ObservableCollection<Info> asd = new ObservableCollection<Info>();
        asd.Add(info);
        Infos = asd;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Info> infos = new ObservableCollection<Info>();
    public ObservableCollection<Info> Infos
    {
        get
        {
            return infos;
        }
        set
        {
            infos = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Infos);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what you are talking about. Seriously, you've just dumped a lot of stuff on the screen.

I think you've gotten yourself very confused - good luck trying to work out what on earth you've done.

One basic answer is that you can navigate to an Mvx-based Activity anywhere you want to simply by:

- creating an `MvxViewModelRequest` - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxViewModelRequest.cs
- converting the request to an `Intent` using the `IMvxAndroidViewModelRequestTranslator` singleton - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/IMvxAndroidViewModelRequestTranslator.cs
- starting that `Intent`

However, I seriously suggest you step out of your current mess and consider a cleaner application flow.

Comment: by navigating like that, I get the same result as I would do the normal `StartActivity`. What u should try is the following: Create an Activity with an optionsmenu. By clicking on a item in the optionsmenu it should open a new Mvx-Activity which is connected to a ViewModel. In the constructor of this ViewModel try to fill a basic MvxListView (which is on the Activity). It won't work. It will only open the new Activity but the list won't get filled as it would if I call `ShowViewModel` from an other ViewModel..